# Authenticating a webhook call in mvc controller http://secretkey:12345@www.example.com

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

Creating a webhook handler in MVC 4 to handle EasyPost webhook calls. I have it all working but now want to add in some authentication.

Easypost suggests a method of including a user name or secret key in the webhook handler url such as: `https://username:secret@www.example.com/easypost-webhook`  [reference](https://www.easypost.com/webhooks-guide). Then I presume extracting that secret key value and comparing to an expected value. I'm attempting to do this via regex.

The problem is I cannot find how to retrieve the `username:secret@` portion of the url in the controller. Tried `Request.RawUrl` and searched all data in the Request Object, to no avail.

My Code:

```
public class ParcelShippingWebHooksController : Controller
{
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ParcelTrackingWebHookHandler()
    {
        //Authenticate request
        string key = AppSettings.ParcelTrackingWebhookSecretKey;
        string url = Request.RawUrl; <---- how get raw url
        string strPattern = @"secretkey:(.*)\@";
        Match match = Regex.Match(url, strPattern);
        if(!match.Success) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        if(match.Value != key) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

        //Convert request to string
        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
        string strWebHookDataRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

        //perform tracking updates
        var webhookAppServ = new ParcelShippingWebHooksAppServ(new InventoryMgmtContext());
        var updateTrackingResult = webhookAppServ.UpdateParcelTrackingStatusFromWebHook(strWebHookDataRequest);

        if (updateTrackingResult.WasSuccessful)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);  // OK = 200
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Easypost reference you are referencing is implying that you use Basic Authentication + SSL.

You'll need to setup MVC to check for that authentication. Here is a sample, taken from this article - [Basic Authentication in MVC 5](http://www.ryadel.com/en/http-basic-authentication-asp-net-mvc-using-custom-actionfilter/):

**BasicAuthenticationAttribute**

```
        public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public string BasicRealm { get; set; }
            protected string Username { get; set; }
            protected string Password { get; set; }

            public BasicAuthenticationAttribute(string username, string password)
            {
                this.Username = username;
                this.Password = password;
            }

            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
                var auth = req.Headers["Authorization"];
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(auth))
                {
                    var cred = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Substring(6))).Split(':');
                    var user = new { Name = cred[0], Pass = cred[1] };
                    if (user.Name == Username && user.Pass == Password) return;
                }
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", BasicRealm ?? "Ryadel"));
                /// thanks to eismanpat for this line: http://www.ryadel.com/en/http-basic-authentication-asp-net-mvc-using-custom-actionfilter/#comment-2507605761
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
```

**Sample Controler**

```
[BasicAuthenticationAttribute("your-username", "your-password", BasicRealm = "your-realm")]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
   ...
}
```